# Help with Business Day Formula

Tags: formula, formula-field

I have created a formula field to calculate the number of Business Days Since Last Activity. Below is the Formula I currently have:

```
CASE(MOD( LastActivityDate - DATE(1985,6,24),7), 
0 , CASE( MOD( Today() - LastActivityDate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,5,6,5,1), 
1 , CASE( MOD( Today() - LastActivityDate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,4,4,4,5,4,6,5,1), 
2 , CASE( MOD( Today() - LastActivityDate ,7),1,2,2,3,3,3,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
3 , CASE( MOD( Today() - LastActivityDate ,7),1,2,2,2,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
4 , CASE( MOD( Today() - LastActivityDate ,7),1,1,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,1), 
5 , CASE( MOD( Today() - LastActivityDate ,7),1,0,2,1,3,2,4,3,5,4,6,5,0), 
6 , CASE( MOD( Today() - LastActivityDate ,7),1,1,2,2,3,3,4,4,5,5,6,5,0), 
999) 
+ 
(FLOOR(( Today() - LastActivityDate )/7)*5)
```

The issue that I am having is that this does not seem to be calculating properly for a few of the values. Listed below is the values I am receiving from a report based on today being Thursday. In the format of how many days in the past the activity was - what I should be getting from the formula - the number I am receiving from the formula field.

- 0 - 0 - 1
- 1 - 1 - 2
- 2 - 2 - 3
- 3 - 3 - 4
- 4 - 3 - 4 ( This is because 4 days ago was a Sunday. Not a business day.)
- 5 - 3 - 4 ( This was Saturday which is still only 3 Bdays ago.)
- 6 - 4 - 5
- 7 - 5 - 6

I hope this makes sense, what seems to be happening is it is adding an extra day for 1 - 3 and then 4 - 7 needs to have one missing. Please let me know if you need anymore clarification.

Comment: Time zone issue? http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122604/i-have-a-formula-field-i-need-to-display-a-certain-value-depending-on-the-local/122627#122627

Comment: Yeah you are probably right. The instance I am in has a time zone of (GMT=01.00)British Summer Time (Europe/London) but the records that this will affect have all been created in the Eastern American time zone.

Comment: Probably important to note that this formula gives you weekdays, and not strictly business days (which would additionally take holidays into account).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured out the issue, in the following [link](https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewSolution?id=000004526) there is a section that states that the formula will include the start and end date. And that is not the case for me. I did not want the end date to be included. So I simply added a minus one to the end of the formula and that seems to have solved the issue.