# Why do I get a null value when I try to use the ActivityDate to set a DateTime value in Process Builder

Tags: formula, process-builder, datetime, event

Pulling my hair out on this one...
I need a process to update events marked as "All-Day" to regular events which start at 8AM and end at 5PM. So I need to set the ActivityDateTime, StartDateTime and EndDateTime values using process builder to specific values. I want to use a formula to set that value because I need the date to match the existing ActivityDate value.

If I try to set the value manually using something like this it works fine:
`DATETIMEVALUE("2016-07-15 13:00:00")`. However when I try to use incorporate the `ActivityDate` field using the field picker, which results in `DATETIMEVALUE("[Event].ActivityDate 13:00:00")`, it doesn't work and instead produces a "null" value.

Workbench tells me that the `ActivityDate` field outputs in the correct format (`YYYY-MM-DD`) so why doesn't this work?

For the record here are versions I tried, all of which produced "null" instead of the value I wanted:

- `DATETIMEVALUE("[Event].ActivityDate 13:00:00")`
- `DATETIMEVALUE("TEXT([Event].ActivityDate) 13:00:00")`
- `DATETIMEVALUE("[Event].ActivityDate" & " " & "13:00:00")`
- `DATETIMEVALUE("TEXT([Event].ActivityDate)" & " " & "13:00:00")`
- `DATETIMEVALUE("TEXT([Event].ActivityDate 13:00:00)")`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, independent of format, you need to add a field update to set `All-Day Event` to `false`. You also need to set `Duration`. For 8AM to 5PM that would be 540.

As for the format itself, you need to use:

```
DATETIMEVALUE(TEXT([Event].ActivityDate) & " 13:00:00")
```

You're going to have some time zone issues (it sets time using GMT), but at least that can get you started. I did outline how to calculate the offest for each user in an answer [here](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/122604/i-have-a-formula-field-i-need-to-display-a-certain-value-depending-on-the-local/122627).

Comment: Thanks, Adrian! For what it's worth I was not required to set a duration; I had set my all-day event flag to false so all I needed was that formatting and I somehow didn't try that version. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

**For All Day Event no hours can be set in Event Date Time.**

That's why, we can have Activity Date of an Event which is of alldayEvent, but ActivityDateTime will be blank.

StartDateTime and EndDateTime will show only the date part and not the time part.

Comment: Sounds like you just have to set `IsAllDayEvent` to false then?

Comment: @AdrianLarson if IsAllDayEvent is false then we can change the time part

Comment: That's a catch in SFDC